# Does there exist a continuous surjection $f:[0,1]\to SL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: analysis

[image]

I know the answer is 'NO'. But I don't quite know how to prove it. Could we use the dimensions of the ambient Euclidean spaces of the domain and range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is obviously yes. You could certainly find a better title.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact, but $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn't compact...

Comment: After your edit, the question in the title still obviously has a positive answer.

Comment: You cannot really use the dimension of the domain and codomain. For example, there exist continuous surjections $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^{23}$. Google for 'Peano curve'.

Answer (score 2):

The image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact.